# Why is this django template not working?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

This was working 2 weeks ago. I can't figure what is causing this error now. I am getting the error `Caught TypeError while rendering: 'int' object is not iterable` on the line in my template where the `FOR` loop starts.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt 
def my_status(request):

    import twitter
    client = twitter.Api()

    #get status of user. get last 100 status only 

    if 'twitternick' in request.POST:
        r = request.POST['twitternick']

        tags = client.GetUserTimeline(r, count='10')

        taglist = [s.text for s in tags]

        ## getting the dictionary

        # create list of lower case words, \s+ --> match any whitespace(s)
        word_list = re.split('\s+',str(taglist))

        # create dictionary of word:frequency pairs
        freq_dic = {}

        # punctuation marks to be removed
        punctuation = re.compile(r'[.?!,":;]') 
        for word in word_list:
            # remove punctuation marks
            word = punctuation.sub("", word)
            word = word.replace("u'",'')
            # form dictionary
            try: 
                freq_dic[word] += 1
            except: 
                freq_dic[word] = 1


        # create list of (key, val) tuple pairs
        tags = [(k,v*10) for k,v in freq_dic.items()]
        tags = dict(tags)

    return render_to_response('twitter_app/mystatus.html', {'latest_status': tags}
```

**data structure for tags**

`{'PAP': 10, 'btw': 10, 'via': 20, 'crowd': 10, 'is': 10, 'half': 10, 'anyway': 10, "#fb'": 10, 'items': 10, '[@leynaaaa': 10, 'are': 10}`

**template**

```
{% extends "twitter_app/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Here comes your status:</h2>

    {% for k, v in latest_status.items %}

    <span style="font-size:{{ v }}px;">{{ k }}</span>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data:

```
{'PAP': 10, 'btw': 10, 'via': 20, 'crowd': 10, 'is': 10, 'half': 10, 'anyway': 10, "#fb'": 10, 'items': 10, '[@leynaaaa': 10, 'are': 10}
```

There's a key called `items`.  Can you pass in a test dictionary without the `items` key to the template to see if it works?

**Workaround:**

Assuming you can't rename the `items` key, you can pass in `{'latest_status': tags.items()}` from your view.  In the template, do a for loop on `{% for k, v in latest_status %}`.

Comment: Holy! You're right! Removing the `items` entry works! Something to do with keywords clashing in the template?

Comment: If you try `{{ latest_status.PAP }}`, the template will try to look for the key `PAP` in the dictionary.  I guess the same is happening for `items`.  It will try to access the key `items` first.  Since it fails on that retrieval, the `items()` method is never called.

Comment: So, how do I fix it? I mean like `.items` is a keyword in Django templates to use in getting the key,value from the dictionary that Im using, how do I prevent it from clashing with the actual words?

Comment: use `iteritems` -- you should use it anyways for a template loop.

Answer (score 0):

latest_status.items is returning a single integer, not an interable data-structure.

Log the value of latest_status.items and tell me what you get.

Comment: Updated question to show you what the output for latest_status (tags)